# Filter out duplicate values in array using php

Tags: php, arrays

Please help me to filter out only duplicate values in array using php.Consider,

```
$arr1 = array('php','jsp','asp','php','asp')
```

Here I would prefer to print only

```
array('php'=>2,
       'asp'=>2)
```

tried it by

```
print_r(array_count_values($arr1));
```

but, its getting count of each element.

Comment: It's getting the count of each element... so what's it doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, I do now. There's not an easy way to do this: BoltClock's approach is probably best.

Comment: I figured it out. OP is asking to only filter out the keys which are reported as having duplicates in `$arr1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, after the comments and rereading your question I got what you mean. You're still almost there with `array_count_values()`:

```
$arr1 = array('php','jsp','asp','php','asp');
$counts = array_count_values($arr1);
```

You just need to remove the entries that are shown as only occurring once:

```
foreach ($counts as $key => $val) {
    if ($val == 1) {
        unset($counts[$key]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** don't want a loop? Use `array_filter()` instead:

```
// PHP 5.3+ only
$counts = array_filter($counts, function($x) { return $x > 1; });

// Older versions of PHP
$counts = array_filter($counts, create_function('$x', 'return $x > 1;'));
```

Comment: Just like the one I was just typing. I'd like to add, though, if the array is large enough, they should set a counter and use a for loop.

Comment: @Ajith: included a non-loop solution.

Comment: You can use array_filter with a callback function that checks if the value is 1 if you really don't want to (write a) loop.

Comment: Your callbacks to `array_filter` don't check the value of `$x`.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want the counts, a simpler way would be to do:

```
$arr1 = array('php','jsp','asp','php','asp');
$dups = array_diff_key($arr1, array_unique($arr1));
```